# How to change combobox appearence with css

Tags: css, combobox, javafx-2

I am working on combobox with javafx 2 and I would like to change the background color of the menu/list in the css. I tried with the following code and some others but nothing work. Do you have any ideas ? Do you think it is possible ?

```
.combo-box .list-view{ 
      -fx-background-color:linear-gradient(#efefef, #b5b5b5, efefef);
 }
.combo-box .cell{
      -fx-background-color:linear-gradient(#efefef, #b5b5b5, #efefef); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot code part, I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.combo-box-popup .cell{
      -fx-background-color:linear-gradient(#efefef, #b5b5b5, #efefef); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok it works, thanks !!!

Also I have change one thing. In a first place, I included the css from the fxml file. Now I include it in the main class :

```
 String css = "application/application.css";
 scene.getStylesheets().clear();
 scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
```

Comment: Please don't use *answers* as comments. If the answer provided is correct, please accept it, and add comments if necessary.